# Bulk remove shape key drivers

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

How do I remove all shape key drivers from an object. Manually removing every driver would take much to long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your object, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> to open console, paste this code: `[b.driver_remove('value') for b in C.active_object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks]`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> to return to *3D Viewport*. The *Properties* view will not automatically update, so you may need to move your mouse over the panel with shape keys to see the change.

A slightly more readable version if you want to save it as text and perhaps modify to apply on multiple objects:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C

for b in C.active_object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
    b.driver_remove('value')
```